# Linux average filesize, specific file type

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have i directory with a loot of different files. Is it possible to calculate the average size of files with a specific file type, in my case *.txt? I want to do it for all *.txt in current directory and subfolders.

Comment: Well you calculate the size of each txt file (using `ls -l`, `du`  or `stat -c %s`'s output depending on needs) and you do the mathematical  arithmetic mean in a loop. So yes it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `stat -c%s *filename*` to get the size of each file, and `ls -l *.txt | wc -l` (note `ls`will give an error if there are no *.txt files in the directory) to get the number of .txt files in the current dir.

Bash, AFIK, doesn't support floating-point arithmetic, so you will need to use some other program to calculate the average size. I suggest using `bc`.

The following script will print the average size of all *.txt files in the current dir

```
#!/bin/bash

tsize=0
fcount=`ls -l *.txt | wc -l`

for f in *.txt
do
    fsize=`stat -c%s $f`
    tsize=`expr $tsize + $fsize`
done
average=`echo "$tsize / $fcount" | bc -l`
echo "Average size: $average"
```

Note that you will get an error from `ls` if there are no .txt files in the current directory.

Comment: `expr` works if your system doesn't have `bc`.

Comment: careful, as this solution doesn't take into account files in sub-folder and does risk producing undesired results, if filenames have special characters (like spaces) -- [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) is a good discussion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `du` command that can produce a grand total of all the files listed:

```
echo $(( $(du -sbc *.txt | tail -1 | cut -f 1) / $(ls *.txt | wc -l) ))
```

Use `-k` or `-m` instead of `-b` for other measurement units.

Answer (score 0):

proposing an alternative, that has less risks with filenames that have special characters, where processing `ls` output will probably produce an undesired result, and also with less piping to multiple commands, that can take a long time if the number of files is huge.

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%s\n' | \
  awk '{size+=$0}
       END {if (NR==0) {printf "No files found!\n";exit;}; 
            printf "# files: %u - Average size: %.3f KB\n", 
            NR, size/NR/1024}'
```

The solution leverages the [linux find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to search for the desired `*.txt` files in current folder and sub-folders and with it's `printf '%s\n'` option that will print the file's size in bytes followed by new-line. Pay attention to links, as decide if you want them included or not in the calculation, adjusting the 'find' expression accordingly.

Each file size printed by find is piped into `awk` that sum's the sizes, and at the END it does divide the sum by the number of files, and by 1024 (to transform bytes into kilo bytes). Also, checks if no file was found, to avoid dividing by zero.

For a short version that only outputs the average size in bytes:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%s\n' | awk '{size+=$0} END {if (NR>0) printf "%.0f\n",size/NR}'
```